# Need help understanding MCNP TMESH tally output

Tags: medical

I am trying to understand the the MCTAL output of a spherical TMESH tally. What I want is to create one tally bin that has the following boundaries 1.9 cm and 2.1 cm in the radial direction, 88 to 92 degrees in theta and 180 to 360 degrees in the phi direction. my input for the tally is

```
C tally card spherical mesh energy tally
TMESH            
SMESH1:p DOSE 1 1 1 1.0 PEDEP MFACT 1 1 0 1.0
CORA1 1.9 2.1                    
CORB1 88 92                      
CORC1 180 360
```

Now what I expect is one result for that volume what I get are eight values as shown below.

```
ntal     1
    1
tally    1   -1   -3
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
f        4    0    1    2    2
  1.90000E+00  2.10000E+00
  0.00000E+00  8.80000E+01  9.20000E+01
  0.00000E+00  1.80000E+02  3.60000E+02
d        1
u        1
s        2
m        1
c        1
e        1
t        1
vals
  5.57481E-04 0.0067  7.68088E-09 0.0493  8.24471E-03 0.0046  1.38395E-07 0.0639
  5.53931E-04 0.0046  7.44313E-09 0.0287  8.24244E-03 0.0042  1.27868E-07 0.0553
```

I am assuming that these eight `vals` correspond to the eight points that that are listed under f. Does TMESH only give one values for individual points on a grid or can it be used to create a volume within which to obtain a result? lastly to what points do what `vals` correspond to ?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix bellow the vals is true value of your meshtally result.
**but**
you must load data to Matlab and reshape it to your mesh tally matrix

Comment: Matlab Command:
a=load('meshdata');
b=reshape(a,..,..)

Answer (score 0):

With your SMESH setup you score both dose and energy deposition. This causes two bins along the segment axis (the "s 2" record in your mctal). Then, you have only 1 bin along the radial direction (1.9-2.1 cm) and actually TWO bins along each of the angular directions (0-88, 88-92, and 0-180, 180-360) which sums up to 2^3 = 8 bins. The mctal file format is described in the manual: it'a 11-dimension loop. In your case only the s, j and k axes are divided, so it's actully a 3D loop (in this exact order: s being the outer, k - the inner loop). Therefore the value for your volume is either the 4th (1.38395E-07 0.0639) or last (1.27868E-07 0.0553) record depending on whether you need dose or energy deposition.